# Two subqueries returning correct data but repeating

Tags: postgresql, time, subquery, common-table-expression

I am attempting to grab products before June 2018 and after December 1st. I figure a simple way to do this is through two sub queries and then just call them next to each other in the outer query. When running this I get the correct data for one of the sub queries and the other is just repeating the same `id` and `created_at` for each different result of the other query.

```
with x as (select id, created_at
    from products p
    where created_at < '2018-06-01'
    and approved = 't'),

y as (select id, created_at 
    from products p
    where created_at > '2018-12-01'
    and approved = 't')

select * from x,y
limit 100;
```

```
Results look like :
id   |   created_at  | id2    |   created_at2
1       2012-12-05     5         2018-12-20 
2       2012-12-06     5         2018-12-20
3       1993-05-23     5         2018-12-20
4       2005-03-10     5         2018-12-20
...
```

```
Expected results:
id   |   created_at  | id2    |   created_at2
1       2012-12-05     5         2018-12-22 
2       2012-12-06     6         2018-12-31
3       1993-05-23     7         2018-12-27
4       2005-03-10     8         2018-12-06
```

Comment: How are the results related? They don’t seem to be. If you just want to show them side by side do that in presentation layer and use separate queries. You’re doing a cross join here so every row in x will be joined with every row in y and you get a lot of results.

Comment: That's a great point. I wasn't sure if there was en easy work around to have them consecutively present their data.

Answer (score 0):

maybe I am not clear on the requirements, but if you want to "grab" products that were created either before June 2018 or after December 1st, you can do that in a single query with OR condition:

```
select id, created_at
    from products p
    where (created_at < '2018-06-01' OR created_at > '2018-12-01')
    and approved = 't'
```